# How to open jstree specific node having multiple jstree in a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, jstree

i'm facing problem with opening **specific** `jstree` node.

i have **multiple** `jstree` in a page and want to control opening and closing of node programitically.

**Question**: i want to open node **banana** programatically ?

**here is my code:**

```js
$(function () {
    $('.jstree-node').jstree();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
<div id="multiple_jstree_wrapper">

  <div class="jstree-node" data-name="apple">
      <ul>
        <li>Apple
          <ul>
            <li>Child node 1</li>
            <li>Child node 2</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   
     <div class="jstree-node" data-name="banana">
      <ul>
        <li>Banana
          <ul>
            <li>Child node 1</li>
            <li>Child node 2</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   
     <div class="jstree-node" data-name="orange">
      <ul>
        <li>Orange
          <ul>
            <li>Child node 1</li>
            <li>Child node 2</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   
</div>
```

**Note**: i want to keep same structure of tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

```
$('div[data-name="banana"]').jstree("open_all");
```